# Speedbar not starting

Tags: speedbar

I'm currently using Xemacs on Windows 10 in compatibility mode and running in VHDL-mode.

When I attempt to open the Speedbar Xemacs returns with `An error occurred while opening speedbar`.

I'm trying to use Xemacs speedbar to discover the VHDL code hierarchy.

I appear to have the `speedbar.el` etc in the `lisp/speedbar` directory so I'm just plain confused. What am I missing?

How can I "install" Speedbar correctly?

Comment: You do realize that the last stable release of Xemacs was 10 years ago?

Comment: Yes however I like the speedbar tool that I have used in the past.

Comment: Speedbar works with GNU Emacs also. You might want to try that.